# Zend Framework 2 Form Errors Not Showing

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I am trying to figure out why Zend Form is not returning errors to my form.

When I take a look inside the: Zdendframework/library/form/form.php file I can see the errors are being generated:

```
public function isValid()
    {
        if ($this->hasValidated) {
            return $this->isValid;
        }

       ...


        if (!$result) {
            $this->setMessages($filter->getMessages());
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

**If I var_dump($filter->getMessages(), I see the errors.**

However when I go back to my form and attempt to dump the messages, there are none available.

**My Controller**

```
        $prg = $this->prg();

    if ($prg instanceof Response) {

        return $prg;

    } elseif ($prg === false) {

        return $this->getVM()->setVariables([
            'form' => $this->registerForm
        ]);

    }

    $this->registerForm->setData($prg);


    if ( ! $this->registerForm->isValid($prg) ) {

        return new ViewModel(['form' => $this->updateForm]);
    }
```

**My form:**

```
public function __construct(
        InputFilterInterface $inputFilter,
        $name = null,
        $options = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct('register', $options);
        $this->register = $inputFilter;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'csrfcheck',
                'type' => 'csrf'
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'user',
                'type' => UserFieldset::class,
                'options' => [
                    'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'submit',
                'type'       => 'submit',
                'attributes' => [
                    'value' => 'Update User',
                    'class' => 'btn green',
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->getInputFilter()->add($this->register, 'user');

        $this->setValidationGroup(
            [
                'csrfcheck',
                'user' => [
                    'id',
                    'email',
                    'firstName',
                    'lastName',
                    'roles',
                    'state'
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
```

**My FieldSet**

```
public function __construct(
        ObjectManager $objectManager,
        User $userPrototype,
        $name = null,
        $options = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($objectManager));
        $this->setObject($userPrototype);

    }

    public function init()
    {

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'id',
                'type'       => 'hidden',
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'uuid',
                'type'       => 'hidden',
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'email',
                'type'       => 'email',
                'options'    => [
                    'label' => 'E-Mail',
                    'instructions' => 'Your email address',
                ],
                'attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control input-large'
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'firstName',
                'type'       => 'text',
                'options'    => [
                    'label' => 'Firstname',
                    'instructions' => 'Alphanumeric characters (A,b,c,d,e..)',
                ],

                'attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'pattern'   => "^[a-zA-Z-]{2,128}$",
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'lastName',
                'type'       => 'text',
                'options'    => [
                    'label' => 'Last name',
                    'instructions' => 'Alphanumeric characters, optional ( \' )',
                ],
                'attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'pattern'   => "^[a-zA-Z'-]{2,128}$",
                ]
            ]
        );


        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'state',
                'type'       => 'select',
                'options'    => [
                    'label' => 'User State',
                    'value_options' => [
                        0 => 'Active',
                        1 => 'Locked',
                        2 => 'Deleted'
                    ]
                ],
                'attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ]
        );

        //@TODO Multiple set to true to make this work remove attributes if this breaks other forms
        $this->add(
            [
                'name'    => 'roles',
                'type'    => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                'options' => [
                    'object_manager' => $this->objectManager,
                    'target_class'   => HierarchicalRole::class,
                    'property'       => 'name',
                    'find_method'    => [
                        'name' => 'getAccessibleRoles'
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Role'
                ],
                'attributes' => [
                    'multiple' => true,
                ]
            ]
        );
```

**My Filter**

```
function __construct(
        ObjectManager $objectManager,
        ObjectRepository $objectRepository
    ) {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name'     => 'id',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => [
                    ['name' => 'Int']
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'     => 'uuid',
                'required' => false
            ]
        );


        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'firstName',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters'    => [
                    ['name' => 'StringTrim']
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 1,
                            'max' => 128
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'lastName',
                'required'   => false,
                'filters'    => [
                    ['name' => 'StringTrim']
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 1,
                            'max' => 128
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'email',
                'required'   => false,
                'filters'    => [
                    ['name' => 'StringTrim']
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 255
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                        'options' => [
                            'useDomainCheck' => true,  //Set to false in order to validate local developer test mails: myemail.dev
                            'message' => "This is not a valid email address"
                        ],

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );



        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'password',
                'required'   => false,
                'filters'    => [
                    ['name' => 'StringTrim']
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => [
                            'max' => 128
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'passwordRepeat',
                'required'   => false,
                'filters'    => [
                    ['name' => 'StringTrim']
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => [
                            'max' => 128
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'roles',
                'required'   => false,
                'validators' => [

                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add( array(
                'name'      => 'state',
                'required'  => false
            ));


    }
```

**And my View**

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
            <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
            <div class="portlet-body form">
                <?php
                $form = $this->form;
                $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url());
                $form->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal form-bordered');
                $form->get('user')->get('roles')->setAttribute('class','form-control input-small select2me');
                $form->get('submit')->setValue('Register new user');
                $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('class','btn green');
                $form->prepare();

                $csrf = $form->get('csrfcheck');
                $user = $form->get('user');
                $id = $user->get('id');
                $state = $user->get('state');
                $email = $user->get('email');
                $firstname = $user->get('firstName');
                $lastname = $user->get('lastName');
                $role = $user->get('roles');
                $sub  = $form->get('submit');

                ?>

                <?= $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
                <?= $this->formElement($csrf); ?>
                <?= $this->formElement($id); ?>
                <?= $this->formElement($state); ?>

                <div class='form-body'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3"><?= $this->formLabel($email); ?></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="input-group" style="text-align:left">
                                <?php echo '<div class="form-group">'.$this->formElement($email).'</div>'; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php if (!empty($this->formElementErrors($email))) echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$this->formElementErrors($email).'</div>';?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3"><?= $this->formLabel($firstname); ?></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="input-group" style="text-align:left">
                                <?php echo '<div class="form-group">'.$this->formElement($firstname).'</div>'; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$this->formElementErrors($firstname).'</div>';  ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3"><?= $this->formLabel($lastname); ?></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="input-group" style="text-align:left">
                                <?php echo '<div class="form-group">'.$this->formElement($lastname).'</div>'; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php if (!empty($this->formElementErrors($lastname))) echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$this->formElementErrors($lastname).'</div>';?>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3"><?= $this->formLabel($role); ?></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="input-group" style="text-align:left">
                                <?php echo '<div class="form-group input-large">'.$this->formElement($role).'</div>'; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php if (!empty($this->formElementErrors($role))) echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$this->formElementErrors($role).'</div>';?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3"><?= $this->formLabel($state); ?></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="input-group" style="text-align:left">
                                <?php echo '<div class="form-group input-large">'.$this->formElement($state).'</div>'; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php if (!empty($this->formElementErrors($state))) echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$this->formElementErrors($state).'</div>';?>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="input-group" style="text-align:left">
                                <?= $this->formElement($sub); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <?= $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

**EDIT**

In the controller if I dump this:

```
    $result = $this->registerForm->getInputFilter()->getMessages();

    die(var_dump($result));
```

This outputs:

> array (size=1)
>     'user' => 
>       array (size=1)
>         'firstName' => 
>           array (size=1)
>             'isEmpty' => string 'Value is required and can't be empty' (length=36)

Comment: Once you have called `isValid()` if you then dump `$this->registerForm->getInputFilter()->getMessages()` what do you see?

Comment: I see the error message when I dump it... I have added it to the opening post.

Comment: Found the error. Its in the controller, I am returning the wrong form on failure. If you add that as your answer, I will give it to you since your suggestion lead me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As deduced from the comments and HappyCoder themselves, the problem lies in the Controller where the wrong form is being returned to the view.

```
if ( ! $this->registerForm->isValid($prg) ) {
    return new ViewModel(['form' => $this->updateForm]);
}
```

Should be:

```
if ( ! $this->registerForm->isValid($prg) ) {
    return new ViewModel(['form' => $this->registerForm]);
}
```